# where is the urllib3 connection pool bound?

Tags: python-requests, connection-pooling, urllib3

If a new requests session is instantiated in different methods like so ...

**myutil.py**

```
import requests

def method1():
    s1 = requests.Session()

def method2():
    s1 = requests.Session()
```

Where is the `requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager` bound? Is it bound globally so that the connection pool is shared between s1 and s2, or is it bound to each method's stack so that s1 and s2 have different connection pools?

If it is bound to each method's stack, what options do I have to share the connection pool?  For example, should I create a [transport adapter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) and then share than between the methods:

**myutil.py**

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

httpAdapter = HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=10, pool_maxsize=100)

def method1():
    s1 = requests.Session()
    s1.mount('https://', httpAdapter)

def method2():
    s1 = requests.Session()
    s2.mount('https://', httpAdapter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some testing and it seems that the pool does NOT get bound globally.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046503/cloudant-python-https-connection-pooling) for more info.